# No unique or primary key for this column list?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've written the code for the parent tables but when I try to run the sql command to generate the child table I'm getting a matching error:

> "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

Parent tables are generated as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dabel3_RetailCenter 
(store_id CHAR (4) NOT NULL, 
store_type VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL, 
store_st_num CHAR (4) NOT NULL,
store_st_name VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL, 
store_city VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL, 
store_state VARCHAR2 (12) NOT NULL, store_ZIP CHAR (5),
CONSTRAINT dabel3_store_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (store_id));
```

```
CREATE TABLE dabel3_Trans_Type (
TM_ID CHAR (2) NOT NULL, 
TM_Type VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT dabel3_Trans_type_TM_ID_pk PRIMARY KEY (TM_ID), 
CONSTRAINT TM_Type_UNQ UNIQUE (TM_TYPE));
```

```
CREATE TABLE dabel3_Trans_Mode (
TM_ID CHAR (2) NOT NULL, 
TM_Route VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL, 
TM_Sched_Num CHAR (3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT dabel3_Trans_mode_pk PRIMARY KEY (TM_ID, TM_Sched_Num), 
CONSTRAINT dabel3_trans_mode_TM_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (TM_ID) REFERENCES dabel3_Trans_Type (TM_ID));
```

However, the child table just won't generate.  Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE dabel3_Shipment (
pkg_track_num VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL, 
pkg_weight CHAR (7) NOT NULL, 
pkg_dimensions VARCHAR2 (20), 
pkg_insurance VARCHAR2 (50), 
pkg_dest_city VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL, 
pkg_dest_state CHAR (2) NOT NULL, 
pkg_dest_ZIP CHAR (5) NOT NULL, 
pkg_due_date DATE NOT NULL,
store_id CHAR (4) NOT NULL, 
TM_ID CHAR (2) NOT NULL, 
TM_Sched_Num CHAR (3) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT dabel3_pkg_track_num_pk PRIMARY KEY (pkg_track_num), 
CONSTRAINT dabel3_shipment_store_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES dabel3_RetailCenter (store_id),
CONSTRAINT dabel3_shipment_TM_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (TM_ID) REFERENCES dabel3_Trans_Type (TM_ID),
CONSTRAINT dabel3_shipment_TM_Sched_Num_fk FOREIGN KEY (TM_Sched_Num) REFERENCES dabel3_Trans_Mode (TM_Sched_Num));
```

Comment: How many columns in the primary key of `dabel3_Trans_Mode`? How many columns do you specify in the declaration of the constraint `dabel3_shipment_TM_Sched_Num_fk`?

Comment: Perhaps not related, but all those `CHAR` columns should be `VARCHAR2`.

Answer (score 2):

If I run into such a problem, I'll chop up the failing statement into bits which are easier to debug:

```
CREATE TABLE dabel3_Shipment (
  pkg_track_num VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL, 
  pkg_weight CHAR (7) NOT NULL, 
  pkg_dimensions VARCHAR2 (20), 
  pkg_insurance VARCHAR2 (50), 
  pkg_dest_city VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL, 
  pkg_dest_state CHAR (2) NOT NULL, 
  pkg_dest_ZIP CHAR (5) NOT NULL, 
  pkg_due_date DATE NOT NULL,
  store_id CHAR (4) NOT NULL, 
  TM_ID CHAR (2) NOT NULL, 
  TM_Sched_Num CHAR (3) NOT NULL
);
Table DABEL3_SHIPMENT created

ALTER TABLE dabel3_Shipment ADD                       
  CONSTRAINT dabel3_pkg_track_num_pk PRIMARY KEY (pkg_track_num); 
Table DABEL3_SHIPMENT altered.

ALTER TABLE dabel3_Shipment ADD                                                     
  CONSTRAINT dabel3_shipment_store_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (store_id) 
  REFERENCES dabel3_RetailCenter (store_id);
Table DABEL3_SHIPMENT altered.

ALTER TABLE dabel3_Shipment ADD                                                     
  CONSTRAINT dabel3_shipment_TM_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (TM_ID) 
  REFERENCES dabel3_Trans_Type (TM_ID);
Table DABEL3_SHIPMENT altered.

ALTER TABLE dabel3_Shipment ADD                                                     
  CONSTRAINT dabel3_sht_TM_Sched_Num_fk 
  FOREIGN KEY (TM_Sched_Num) 
  REFERENCES dabel3_Trans_Mode (TM_Sched_Num);
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column
```

So, the error is in this clause. There is no primary or unique key on the referenced column. Once we fix that...

```
ALTER TABLE dabel3_Trans_Mode ADD 
  CONSTRAINT dabel3_Trans_mode_sm_unq UNIQUE(TM_Sched_Num);
Table DABEL3_TRANS_MODE altered.
```

... the constraint compiles:

```
ALTER TABLE dabel3_Shipment ADD                                                     
  CONSTRAINT dabel3_sht_TM_Sched_Num_fk 
  FOREIGN KEY (TM_Sched_Num) 
  REFERENCES dabel3_Trans_Mode (TM_Sched_Num);
Table DABEL3_SHIPMENT altered.
```

EDIT:

@The Impaler is obviously right, a composite key would be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The last table creation of `dabel3_Shipment` is wrong at:

```
CONSTRAINT dabel3_shipment_TM_Sched_Num_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (TM_Sched_Num) 
REFERENCES dabel3_Trans_Mode (TM_Sched_Num) -- NOT a key
```

The problem is that `dabel3_Trans_Mode`'s column `TM_Sched_Num` is NOT a key. In order to establish a foreign key, it must *point* to a key in the remote table.

The referenced table has a composite key `(TM_ID, TM_Sched_Num)`. You are trying to use part of the key, and that's not a key. Use it whole, both columns, and problem solved.

For example, you could do:

```
CONSTRAINT dabel3_shipment_TM_Sched_Num_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (TM_ID, TM_Sched_Num) 
REFERENCES dabel3_Trans_Mode (TM_ID, TM_Sched_Num)
```